# Android simply save and read file

Tags: java, android, file

I want to save and read a String on the internal storage of the Android device. I want to (if the file doesn't already exist) write the file, edit the file and read the file. What is the easiest and best way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google. Stackoverflow is not a substitute - although you could search here.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, you will use standard Java I|O, like you have done on your previous Java projects.

To get at a file on internal storage, you have two major options:

1. Use `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` to get an `InputStream` and `OutputStream` on a file in the root of your internal storage, respectively
2. Use `getFilesDir()` to get a `File` object pointing to the root of your internal storage, from which you can create subdirectories, create streams and readers for input and output, etc.

Comment: I still don't understand how it works. Where do I use what for? Do you know a clear tutorial?

Comment: @user1380611: If you do not know Java I/O, then I humbly suggest that you spend some time learning Java before getting into Android development. There are countless resources for learning Java, from Web sites to books to courses. With respect to using the Android methods for accessing internal storage, you can read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and look at sample projects like https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/ReadWrite

Answer (score 0):

To write values:

Call edit() to get a SharedPreferences.Editor.
Add values with methods such as putBoolean() and putString().
Commit the new values with commit()
To read values, use SharedPreferences methods such as getBoolean() and getString().

Here is an example that saves a preference for silent keypress mode in a calculator:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```